# Photoshop JS specify font

Tags: javascript, photoshop, photoshop-script

I'm trying to modify a script to work for what I need it to do and keep getting the "TypeError: undefined is not an object ... I can't figure out why though. I've copy and pasted pretty much everything. The problem line as setting the font to Adobe Garamond.

Script listener has these lines that I think are related but, I don't know JS enough to get it.

```
    var idfontPostScriptName = stringIDToTypeID( "fontPostScriptName" );
    desc22.putString( idfontPostScriptName, """AGaramondPro-Regular""" );
    var idFntN = charIDToTypeID( "FntN" );
    desc22.putString( idFntN, """Adobe Garamond Pro""" );
    var idFntS = charIDToTypeID( "FntS" );
    desc22.putString( idFntS, """Regular""" );
```

My script looks like

```
    // this script is a variation of the script addTimeStamp.js that is installed with PH7

    //OPENED document has size
    if ( documents.length > 0 )
    {
var originalDialogMode = app.displayDialogs;
app.displayDialogs = DialogModes.ERROR;
var originalRulerUnits = preferences.rulerUnits;
preferences.rulerUnits = Units.PIXELS;

try
{
    var docRef = activeDocument;

    // Now create a text layer at the front
    var myLayerRef = docRef.artLayers.add();
    myLayerRef.kind = LayerKind.TEXT;
    myLayerRef.name = "Filename";

    var myTextRef = myLayerRef.textItem;

    // strip the extension off
    var fileNameNoExtension = docRef.name;
    fileNameNoExtension = fileNameNoExtension.split( "." );
    if ( fileNameNoExtension.length > 1 ) {
        fileNameNoExtension.length--;
    }
    fileNameNoExtension = fileNameNoExtension.join(".");

    myTextRef.contents = fileNameNoExtension;



    // off set the text to be in the middle
    myTextRef.position = new Array( docRef.width / 2, docRef.height / 2 );
    myTextRef.size = 135;
     myTextRef.textItem.font = 'AGaramondPro-Regular';
}
catch( e )
{
    // An error occurred. Restore ruler units, then propagate the error back
    // to the user
    preferences.rulerUnits = originalRulerUnits;
    app.displayDialogs = originalDialogMode;
    throw e;
}

// Everything went Ok. Restore ruler units
preferences.rulerUnits = originalRulerUnits;
app.displayDialogs = originalDialogMode;
    }
    else
    {
alert( "You must have a document open to add the filename!" );
    }
```

Answer (score 1):

Oh my hell. Just answered my own question again. Sorry guys.

```
    myTextRef.font = 'AGaramondPro-Regular';
```

Comment: Photoshop tends to use Postscript font names (if memory serves) - which complicates matters :)